# HTML file served as static in AWS Elastic Beanstalk with HTTPS are served as string

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've deployed my Node.js + Express API on AWS EB and routed a custom domain with its HTTPS certificate.

Then I've a static HTML file in static directory of this environment "/public" and the HTML file is served greatly if opened on a browser with HTTP.

But when I open the same HTML file with HTTPS it seems to serve the file content as a string in this way:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
        "<!DOCTYPE html> ... {all my html page content}"
    </pre>
    </body>
 </html>
```

How can i serve this html file with HTTPS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was that i firstly setted content-type response header like this:

```
function decode(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    next();
}
app.use(decode);
```

Removing this it worked.

I still don't know why it worked with HTTP and not with HTTPS.